# Почему лист пустой в тесте? Spring boot, Rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

```
@SpringBootTest
class DetailServiceV1Test {

@Mock
private DetailRepository detailRepository;

@Autowired
private final DetailService detailService = new DetailServiceV1(detailRepository);

@Test
void getUsedDetails() {
    Detail detail = new Detail(101L, "children", "code", new HashSet<>(), 100L, 0, 100L, new 
    ArrayList<>());
    Detail parent = new Detail(100L, "parent", "code", new HashSet<>(), null, 1, 100L, new 
    ArrayList<>());

    List<Detail> detailList = List.of(parent, detail);

    when(detailRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(detailList);

    List<Detail> usedDetails = detailService.getUsedDetails(detail);
    System.out.println(usedDetails.toString());
    Detail test = usedDetails.get(0);
    assertEquals(test, parent);
}
```

}

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так прикручиваю. Лист userDetails пустой, хотя по логике в нем должен быть объект parent.

```
public class DetailServiceV1 implements DetailService {

private final DetailRepository detailRepository;

public DetailServiceV1(DetailRepository detailRepository) {
    this.detailRepository = detailRepository;
}

 @Override
public List<Detail> getUsedDetails(Detail detail) {

    List<Detail> details = detailRepository.findAll();
    List<Detail> usedDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Detail detailInList : details) {
        if (Objects.equals(detailInList.getParentId(), detail.getId())) {
            usedDetails.add(detailInList);
            log.info("find used detail");
        }
    }
    return usedDetails;
}
```

DetailRepository наследует JpaRepository<Detail, Long>

Comment: Методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` у класса `Detail` переопределили?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець да, lombok стоит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется вам нужно использовать не @Mock (это для юнит-тестов), а @MockBean если вы хотите заменить какой-то бин в спринговом контексте на мок.

То, что вы настраиваете мок - кажется никак не влияет на на бин DetailService и идет вызов реального метода.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final DetailRepository detailRepository = mock(DetailRepository.class);
```

Вместо аннотации @Mock, и @autowared не нужен

Вроде как, именно в этом и была проблема.
Оставлю этот комментарий, вдруг кому пригодится.